# How does App Engine's new "Minimum Pending Latency" setting affect warmup requests?

Tags: google-app-engine

How does App Engine's new "Minimum Pending Latency" setting affect warmup requests?

If I set a "Minimum pending latency" of 10 seconds, will my app still start up instances with warmup requests even if the pending latency never reaches that high?

My hope is that it will, because my app's cold start time is about 15 seconds, and I was hoping that by setting a high "minimum pending latency", it would make it so it doesn't try to start an instance on a user facing request (making the user wait 15 seconds), but it will still start up instances in the background with warmup requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The App Engine runtime will not start new instances as long as your pending latency is below the value you specify. This includes warmup requests. Once latency exceeds the value you specify, the runtime will start up new instances, using warmup requests when possible.